# Yii2 Undefined index

Tags: yii2

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, у меня мозг уже не хочет работать...

С помощью ArrayHelper::map() привожу свои данные к массиву $hasanArray

```
Array
    (
        [N] => 12
        [R] => 16
        [S] => 21
    )
```

Массив имеет именно такой вид - инфа 100%

После чего я пытаюсь обратиться к нему

```
if ($hasanArray['R'] > $AVG['R'] + $sqr['R'])
```

После чего получаю

```
Undefined index: R
```

Есть идеи?

Код:

```
$query = 'SELECT pmh.scale, SUM(pht.value) as value FROM psy_hasan_tmp pht JOIN psy_mdl_hasan pmh'
. ' ON pmh.question_id = pht.question WHERE pht.userid = :user GROUP BY pht.userid, pmh.scale';

$hasanArray = ArrayHelper::map(MdlPDOResults::findBySql($query, [':user' => $user])->asArray()->all(), 'scale', 'value');
$hasanStr = '';

if ($hasanArray['R'] > $AVG['R'] + $sqr['R'])
   $hasanStr .= 'V';
elseif ($hasanArray['R'] < $AVG['R'] - $sqr['R'])
   $hasanStr .= 'N';
else $hasanStr .= 'S';
```

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у меня массив с индексами R S N и соответствующими целочисленными значениями

Comment: значит хэлпер не отрабатывает..... покажите полный код от хэлпера, сам хэлпер и после и `print_r` массива сразу после срабатывания хэлпера

Comment: @АлексейШиманский проблема то в том, что print_r после хелпера выводит именно Array
    (
        [N] => 12
        [R] => 16
        [S] => 21
    )

Comment: а что такое $AVG и $sqr? откуда они берутся? может на R  ругается именно на них, а не на $hasanArray

Comment: @АлексейШиманский значение $AVG Array
(
    [N] => 14.6454
    [R] => 18.7265
    [S] => 24.8554
) А $sqr  Array
(
    [R] => 5.6719146277931
    [N] => 6.9858467392703
    [S] => 10.058326573039
)

Comment: Без полного кода, а именно: входных данных (откуда получаете значения, в какой момент), реализации логики в map это будет только гадание на кофейной гуще))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский добавил в вопрос.

Comment: неужели и  `print_r($AVG);print_r($svg)`, перед самой строчкой в которой ошибка, выводятся массивы в которых есть индекс R? Попробуйте проверить с помощью `array_key_exists` наличие R на каждый массив и посмотреть в каком будет false

Comment: @Pa3Py6aka завтра специально скриншоты сделаю =)

Comment: @Pa3Py6aka вызов return array_key_exists('R', $hasanArray) . ' ' . array_key_exists('R', $AVG) . ' ' . array_key_exists('R', $sqr); возвращает строку '1 1 1'

Comment: Ну прям мистика! А если написать `if (isset($hasanArray['R']) && isset($AVG['R']) && isset($svg['R'])) { 
if ($hasanArray['R'] > $AVG['R'] + $sqr['R']) { $hasanStr .= 'V'; }
elseif ($hasanArray['R'] < $AVG['R'] - $sqr['R']) {  $hasanStr .= 'N'; }
else { $hasanStr .= 'S'; }
} else { die('no R'); }` что будет?

Comment: @Pa3Py6aka ну иссеты я поставил и теперь эти куски кода не выполняются)))

Comment: срабатывает `die('no R');`? Тогда вместо `die('no R');` пропиши на отдельных строчках `echo $hasanArray['R'];` , `echo $AVG['R'];`, `echo $sqr['R'];` и глянь в какой строчке будет ошибка, уже легче будет)

Comment: @Pa3Py6aka оставил просто `if (isset($hasanArray['R'])` - попёрло. Видимо что-то с двумя другими массивами, но суть в том, что не смотря на это он считает все показатели верно... Спасибо за помощь. Пойду дальше исправлять косяки =)